# Angular filter checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a group of checkboxes defined like this:

```
         span(ng-repeat='angle in anglesList')
            input(type='checkbox', ng-model='angle.selected')
            |  {{angle.angle}}
            br
          hr
```

On the JS side:

```
$scope.anglesList = [
      {
        angle: "Angle 1",
        selected: true
      }, {
        angle: "Angle 2",
        selected: true
      }, {
        angle: "Angle 3",
        selected: true
      }, {
        angle: "Angle 4",
        selected: true
      }
    ];
```

And a filter on my ng-repeat of items:

```
.filter("angleFilter", function($filter) {
    return function(items, search) {
      var resultsAngle = [];
      if (!search) {
        return items;
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          for (var k = 0; k < items[i].angles.length; k++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < search.length; j++) {
              if (items[i].angles[k] === search[j].angle && search[j].selected === true) {
                var e = $filter('filter')(resultsAngle, {_id:items[i]._id});
                if (e.length > 0) {

                } else {
                  resultsAngle.push(items[i]);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return resultsAngle;
      }
    }
  })
```

On first load, because all of the angleList items in the angleList array are set to selected: true, they all load as checked. And as I uncheck them, the items disappear depending on if that item has that angle. This is inconvinient because if I want to only see the items that have Angle 4, I must manually uncheck Angle 1, Angle 2, and Angle 3. What I would like to have happen is for all of the checkboxes to be unchecked initially, but still have the items show up. Then when one check box is checked, filter down the items to just that one angle. Not sure how to do this. Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the ng-repeat of items that I'm filtering for:

```
    tr(ng-repeat='detail in launchesList | orderBy: "+launchDate" | filterPastDates |  filter:{launchName:launchName} | filter:{vendorName:vendorName} | angleFilter:anglesList)
```

Comment: You are setting all of the checkbox models as true since you are trying to assign property of angleList object array. You can make all the selected fields false as default and when the checkbox is checked update the selected field to true.

Comment: When I set all of the fields to false, on the initial load, nothing loads in my list though, because the filter is showing that everything is empty.

Comment: Because you are showing the labels according to checkbox status. The thing you should do is to define div for each label and checkbox next to them. After that you should set the checkboxes to false as default. And you can call a function after clicking the checkbox and change the status of labels whether you want to show them or not. I'm not free atm. I'll create and answer when I'm available.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my post with the ng-repeat that I'm going through with my filters on it for context. I understand what you mean based on starting them as all false by default, but then what would I filter by?